# When npm installs the same dependencies of different versions for different root dependencies, where are they located and how are they tracked?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I had no good idea on how to word this, but let me try to show an example and explain.

taking a look at the `json5` dep used in our app via `npm ls json5` you will see 2 different verions of 2.2.1 and 1.0.1

```
├─┬ @babel/core@7.20.5
│ └── json5@2.2.1
├─┬ babel-loader@8.3.0
│ └─┬ loader-utils@2.0.4
│   └── json5@2.2.1 deduped
└─┬ eslint-plugin-import@2.26.0
  └─┬ tsconfig-paths@3.14.1
    └── json5@1.0.1
```

Now my question relates to how npm installs and knows which version to use for which dependency (no matter how deep) and where are the located.

For example on my `where are the located.` part of my question.

When i search my root node_modules folder, and look for `eslint-plugin-import` dep, i find a node-modules within it but it only 3 things, I thought i would find another folder that is labeled `tsconfig-path` and inside that, find another node_modules folder that contains `json5@1.0.1`. But i dont, the only thing i do find is my root node_modules folder contains all three, `eslint-plugin-import`, `tsconfig-paths`, and `json5`.

I also noticed, that even thought this dep tree shows version 1.0.1 and 2.2.1 for `json5`, my root node_modules folder is the 2.2.1 version.

So that makes me wonder, where is the 1.0.1 version located, and how does it keep track of these different verions for these dep trees to know which one to us since i couldnt even find the 1.0.1 version physically anywhere. I guess i need a better understanding on how npm works and how the npm ecosystem for dependencies.

Sorry for long explanation, its just hard for me to rely my thoughts in a shorter summary.

Comment: look in eslint-plugin-import/node_modules/tsconfig-paths/node_modules/json5